# Default date format for TEXT function in Excel

Tags: excel, date, text, format, default

Excel document.

I have a date value in a cell. Then I have used TEXT function to format this date as a text:

```
=TEXT(A1;"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

It works. But does a default value exist for date format? Something like this:

```
=TEXT(A1;date)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using TEXT function? - in most cases it's best to use cell formatting to format the cell in required date format - if you use a format beginning with * then it will change depending on regional settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't as it would be locale specific. (e.g. US a default could be MM/DD/YYYY, in the UK  DD/MM/YYYY. That would make spreadsheets very brittle).

The only standards are ISO-8601 which specifies YYYYMMDD and ISO-8601-Ext which specifies YYYY-MM-DD.

I would suggest you are always explicit with your formatting. In that respect, by not supplying a default, Excel helps.

Comment: >>No it doesn't as it would be locale specific. (e.g. US a default could be MM/DD/YYYY, in the UK DD/MM/YYYY.<<
But this is what I'm going to achieve: I'll share my doc among some users and every user will see a date field as he usually used to see.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason for using TEXT format you can use cell formatting to format dates - as per my comment on your question, use one of the formats beginning with * and the format will change according to region

Comment: Finally I should have a date range: "between 01/01/2010 and 10/10/2012". That's why I'm using TEXT function to convert date values: "between " & TEXT(A!;"...") & " and " & TEXT(A2;"...").
Unfortunately, TEXT doesn't support wildcard '*'.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

As a workaround, which may work in some cases, you could use `=TODAY()` in one cell (say, A1), which should have the default date format, and `=CELL("format",A1)` in A2, which will contain a result given in a table in http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/cell-function-HP010062392.aspx.
You would have to inquire about the result being `D1` to `D5`, and then translate it into a suitable format string.